# Set boundries for Mapbox LineString to follow oceans

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've created a map where the user adds all blogposts as markers and I'm using LineString to connect all markers.

Is it possible to draw a line between two points in the ocean, where the line never touches land? Say I have a point in the Atlantic Ocean and one in the Pacific Ocean and I would want the LineString to never touch land and therefore search its way intelligently only over seas.

The user owns a sailboat and is traveling the world with it. I guess every waterline where a sailing yacht passes through is valid and the shortest way should be used. The user will for sure pass the panama canal on his way.

```
const geojson = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [
            
                {
                    type: 'Feature',
                    geometry: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [17.5, 47.03]
                    },
                    properties: {
                        title: 'Test',
                        image: '/en/img/asset.png',
                        postDate: 'Sunday, 31. Juli 2022',
                        locationFlag: 'ai',
                        locationLabel: 'Anguilla',
                        postLink: '/en/logbook/test',
                        linkLabel: 'Read more'
                    }
                },  
        ]
    };

map.on('load', () => {
    
    map.addSource('route', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'properties': {},
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [
                    
                        [17.5, 47.03],
                    
                        [14.4804813, 40.6943046],
                    
                        [18.2, 47.3],
                    
                ]
            }
        }
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'route',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'route',
        'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round',
        },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': 'rgba(56, 62, 86, 1)',
            'line-width': 4
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the Panama Canal part of the sea? Is the Northwest Passage? Are you modeling this as a raster or a vector?

Comment: I've created a map where the user adds all blogposts as markers and I'm using LineString to connect all markers. The user owns a sailboat and is traveling the world with it. I guess every waterline where a sailing yacht passes through is valid and the shortest way should be used. The user will for sure pass the panama canal on his way.

Comment: You've got a ton of work ahead, constructing a triangular tesselation of the globe, clipping it with land and hazards to navigation (like pirate nests), and adding canals and other navigation features, then weighting the segments with actual distance (potentially weighted by prevailing winds), and connecting the points on the eastern edge of the model with the western equivalents and zero weight, then running a linear cost path model across 5-50 million segments. No idea if Mapbox can even do that, but kinda doubt it.